# Python (3.12) I'm having massive problems merely trying to install "pip aiohttp" for example (& other graphql modules)

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cython

OK, so I'm trying to install GraphQL modules w PIP.

GraphQL requires Cython... Apparently some GraphQL code is in C++ ??

The PIP install procedure identifies that I need MS C++ 14+.

I don't want to install the ENTIRE SDK, so I'm tried to install min components, hopefully including the compiler.

Do I assume the compiler is called "CL.EXE".

Do I need to make sure CL.EXE is installed (ie find it) & put it in the PATH var?

Mixing languages like this is totally new in Python to me....

[image]

I've also tried installing py_MSVC, and running some python its author suggests:

import os

import pyMSVC

environment = pyMSVC.Environment()

print(environment)

os.environ.update(environment)

--->  Running code merely produces an error saying it can't find a C++ SDK.

Comment: "Running code merely produces an error saying it can't find a C++ SDK" - Then installing said SDK seems like the obvious and simple solution, don't you think..?

Comment: C++/CLI is not the C++ SDK. That is managed c++ on the .net platform.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily; an error message does not always mean what it says.... depends on the programmer.

However I did in the end decide that, probably, I might need the entire SDK, since that would include all the libs & I didn't know whether the modules PIP was building needed loads of dependencies (libs).

So....  I did install entire C++ SDK in the end.... & yes, everything did work immediately after.